# SQL Server Management Studio restarts when hit 'new query"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using:

[image]

And everything works fine, I can even see reports performance:

[image]

But when I hit 'new query', I get this, and SSMS restarts automatically:

[image]

Most of what I have to do is on the query window, so this is quite irritating

error:
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2017.140.17230.0, time stamp: 0x5aa77b02
Faulting module name: WindowsBase.ni.dll, version: 4.7.2558.0, time stamp: 0x59d41ae3
Exception code: 0x80131623
Fault offset: 0x002809a3
Faulting process id: 0x3ddc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3d894161c96fd
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\d9eac8ec5a604324b2ad7792cf8d8ed4\WindowsBase.ni.dll
Report Id: 9889b185-67cd-4cb4-928f-d89b5801d2f3
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.

Message: Unrecoverable system error.
Stack at System.Environment.FailFast
   at MS.Internal.Invarian

Comment: I know its not ideal, but I think the only thing you could do here, is either contact your IT department in your workplace (providing you are in the workplace) or delete SSMS and reinstall

Comment: no IT department. I had 17.6, now I am using 17.5 and I have the issue still.

Comment: that is strange, is it locolhost you are trying to query or is it an external server?

Comment: SSMS works. It's impossible to even guess wha'ts wrong with *your* machine since you didn't provide any information. Did you check Event Viewer? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint the server you use doesn't matter for the *client*. Besides, SSMS isn't broken. I've used all editions up to the latest

Comment: @Chicago1988 unless you provide something more concrete, the only advice one can give is to uninstall the current version, *download the full installation package again*, not just the web installer, and install the latest version again. Sometimes the downloaded files are corrupted. If 15.6 was broken a *lot* of people would have noticed already

Comment: I'm using 17.5 on Windows 10 16299 and it #worksforme. This is not really the sort of thing that can be diagnosed from a distance.

Comment: I found the error on event viewer, shall I add as text or picture? (I tried as text,but it recognizes it as code?!)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the database giving you the problem in the object explorer.
2. Click ‘Properties’
3. Click ‘Options’
4. Set ‘Auto Close’ to False